# Thunderbolt 3 Charging not working

Tags: battery, thunderbolt, charging

I recently dual booted Ubunutu 16.04 and Windows 10 on my Razer Blade Stealth 2016 and have the system working like a dream. The only problem is my laptop wont charge while using Ubuntu. It uses a thunderbolt 3 port for charging, so I think it could be a driver problem, but I can't seem to find any relevant information on the topic. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a fresh install and now it works perfectly